# Python Beginner Coder Problems

Tags: python

I'm working on a UI and having trouble running my code through the second function. The initial function of the UI is supposed to take the client's full name and say ("Hello + full_name) and then take the client's date of birth and subtract it from the current date to calculate the client's age. The first part of this code goes through clearly I just do not know how to pass the code onto the second part of the code where the code prints out "Sorry we can not create your account at this time" or "Let's move forward with the next steps". Any help or advice would assist.

```
from datetime import datetime

full_name = input("Hi my name is Jacko. What is your full name?")
print ("Hello" + full_name)

class Jacko:
    dob = input("Input your birthday, please: ")
    date_of_birth = datetime.strptime(dob, "%Y %m %d")
    current_date = datetime.today()
    current_age = (current_date - date_of_birth) /365
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
            
    def age (self):
        self.current_age = current_age
        if self.current_age < 21:
            print ("Sorry we can not create your account at this time")
        else:
            print ("Let's move forward with the next steps")
```

Comment: Why do you need a class?

Comment: defining a class achieves nothing if you never use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things not implemented properly in this example. For example, I don't see how you plan to use `Jacko` class.

Secondly, the age is supposedly supplied by the user, so it should be in the `__init__` and not be a class attribute. Class attributes are exactly the same for all instances of the class so unless you want all users to have the same age, age goes in the `__init__`.

When calculating `current_age` I assume we'd be interested in full years so use integer division instead of regular one. So I'd re-write the code like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

class Jacko:    
    def __init__(self, name, dob):
        print(f'Hello {name}')
        self.name = name
        self.dob = datetime.strptime(dob, "%Y %m %d")
        self.current_age_years = datetime.today().year - self.dob.year
            
    def age (self):
        if self.current_age_years < 21:
            print ("Sorry we can not create your account at this time")
        else:
            print ("Let's move forward with the next steps")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    full_name = input("Hi my name is Jacko. What is your full name? ")
    dob = input('What is your date of birth?' )
    
    jc = Jacko(full_name, dob)
    jc.age()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I'm still new to this.  Can you further explain this part of the function:
if __name__ == '__main__':. What does it mean?

Comment: That is just a standard format used in python scripts since any script in Python is also potentially a module that can be imported by other scripts. What this says in human language: *"Execute the below code if and only if executing as a script but don't execute if imported by other package"*

Comment: Hi, I just run this code and it's running into a couple of errors. The code is supposed to return the user's name back and say hi "user's name". It does not do that I keep running into a Value Error when I run it. If you can try out both codes and see if you run into an error.

Comment: Made some minor changes. The updated code works fine for me. @Don_de.coder